# Remove duplicate values of a pandas dataframe particular columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with multiple columns and I want to select the subset of columns and remove the duplicate values from it.

I do not want to remove rows, Only want to remove particular column duplicate values.

My data frame looks like:

[image]

I want to remove duplicates from these columns `["PLACEMENT # NAME", "IMPRESSIONS","ENGAGEMENTS","DPEENEGAGEMENTS"]`, so my out will look like.

[image]

Comment: It's OK question - don't worry.  I think you need `pivot_table`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table

Comment: @Ingaz It isn't. I don't see a [mcve] here with any text data, only images.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Are you proposing for novice to do: a) create excerpts from quite complex pandas dataframe, b) find some kind of pandas playground (I don't know of existence of such service), c) upload this data, d) create "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"?? If she could do so - she would have no need to ask about `pivot_table` method.

Comment: In the future, please add your data in an easy to use format. Either by providing code that creates your sample data, or in a format that is easy to copy and paste. The latter can be accomplished with something like `df.head().to_clipboard()`

Comment: Thanks, guys for your response. @coldspeed. Do you have any posted example which is meeting the expectation of community, please share?

Comment: @Ingaz Thanks for your support. I'm newbie here and downvoting gets me block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some of your data

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'PLACEMENT # NAME': ['Blend of Vdx Display', 'Blend of Vdx Display',
                                        'Blend of Vdx Display', 'Blend of Vdx Display'],
                  'PRODUCT': ['Display', 'Display', 'Mobile', 'Mobile'],
                  'VIDEONAME': ['Features', 'TVC', 'video1', 'video2'],
                  'COST_TYPE': ['CPE', 'CPE', 'CPE', 'CPE'],
                  'Views': [1255, 10479, 156, 20],
                  '50_pc_video': [388, 2402, 38, 10],
                  '75_pc_cideo_10': ['', '', '', ''],
                  'IMPRESSIONS': [778732,778732,778732,778732],
                  'ENGAGEMENTS': [13373, 13373, 13373, 13373],
                  'DPEENGAGEMENTS': [7142, 7142, 7142, 7142]})
```

You can accomplish what you want with `.loc` + `.duplicated()`

```
dup_cols = ['PLACEMENT # NAME', 'IMPRESSIONS', 'ENGAGEMENTS', 'DPEENGAGEMENTS']
df.loc[df.duplicated(dup_cols), dup_cols] = ''
```